# How to return from WCF service event per session to my main form

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf

I `Winform` application that host `WCF` service with simple method that received string from client, this method open new instane of other class that open process and do stuff:

```
namespace ServiceLibrary

    [ServiceContract()]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string startProcess(string str);
    }


[ServiceBehavior(
    ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple,
    InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]

public class service1 : IService1
{
        public string startProcess(string str)
        {
            Jo job = new job();
            job.Event += job_Event;
            job.Start(str);
        }

}
```

Inside `Job` class i have event that raised event with all my class properties (name, size etc...)

```
public delegate void StartEventHandler(Job obj);
public event StartEventHandler Event;
```

and from my service a im also subscride this event and from this event i want to send to my main form this object in order to uodate my UI:

```
job.Event += job_Event;

    public void job_Event(Job obj)
    {
        // Send to to my main form and update UI
    }
```

My problem is because my ServiceBehavior is `ConcurrencyMode.Multiple` and not `Single` i have several sessions of my service and i don't know how to raised an event in my form.

this is how i created my service from my main form:

```
urlService = "net.tcp://" + ipAddress.ToString() + ":8000/MyService";
ServiceHost new ServiceHost(typeof(ServiceLibrary.service1));

                    NetTcpBinding tcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding();
                    tcpBinding.TransactionFlow = false;
                    tcpBinding.Security.Transport.ProtectionLevel = System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign;
                    tcpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.Windows;
                    tcpBinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ServiceLibrary.IService1), tcpBinding, urlService);
                    ServiceMetadataBehavior metadataBehavior;
                    metadataBehavior = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
                    if (metadataBehavior == null)
                    {
                        // Create the proxy object that is generated via the svcutil.exe tool
                        metadataBehavior = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
                        metadataBehavior.HttpGetUrl = new Uri("http://" + _ipAddress.ToString() + ":8001/MyService");
                        metadataBehavior.HttpGetEnabled = true;
                        metadataBehavior.ToString();
                        host.Description.Behaviors.Add(metadataBehavior);
                        urlMeta = metadataBehavior.HttpGetUrl.ToString();
                    }

                    host.Open();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a class with static functions to access for your form. What about something like this?

```
public class MyFormFunctions
{
    public static job_Event(Job obj)
    {
         /// do something to form
    }
}
        public string startProcess(string str)
        {
            Job job = new job();            
            MyFormFunctions.job_Event(job);

        }
```